# Big dict as a module crashes and lag ?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

The problem is kinda simple , i started a small project in eclipse and pydev and in this project i have to import a 14Mb .py file that only has a dict in it . 
Everything worked fine and dandy until i got to the part where i have to import the file in my main script  , ever since that moment eclipse started to crash saying it's out of memory .
After a few searches on the net i found the "eclipse memory problem" so i adjusted the configuration of the eclipse.ini file to :

```
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

That helped a bit but not fixed the problem . Because a new kinda problem emerged , from time to time the cpu usage jumps from 2-3% to 50-70% and some times this leads to a complete eclipse crash . After other searches on the net i found something about the autocomplete feature in eclipse and turned it off but nothing changed .

And now i em clueless regarding this eclipse pydev and "big" modules problem .
Any help is highly appreciated .

I have 2.5 Ghz dualcore and 3Gb of ram on a windows 7 machine , and while i em still in this mess can someone point a optimal configuration for my machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would probably be putting the information of that dict in a separate non-python file and populating it when you import the module (so, PyDev wouldn't really parse it).

Comment: i thought of that but that just eliminates the purpose  , but if i have no choice i guess i em going to go with that . thx for the sugestion!

Comment: You can try adding #@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore to the top of the file to see if the situation is improved (at least PyDev won't try to code-analyze it). But still, it'll have to parse that file when doing code-analysis for other modules...